# C# simple custom encrypting

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm making a simple custom encrypting in C#.NET, the encryption passes succesfully, but the decrypting goes wrong. The algorithm is very intuitive, but I don't know why it's decrypted wrong.
Here is my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Encrypting 
            byte[] initial_text_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initial_text_tb.Text);
            byte[] secret_word_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret_word_tb.Text);
            byte[] encrypted_bytes = new byte[initial_text_bytes.Length];




            int secret_word_index = 0;
            for (int i=0; i < initial_text_bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (secret_word_index == secret_word_bytes.Length)
                {
                    secret_word_index = 0;
                }
                encrypted_bytes[i] = (byte)(initial_text_bytes[i] + initial_text_bytes[secret_word_index]);
                secret_word_index++;
            }



          //  String s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted_bytes);
                //new String(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(encrypted_bytes));

            text_criptat_tb.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Decrypting
            byte[] initial_text_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text_criptat_tb.Text);
            byte[] secret_word_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret_word_tb.Text);
            byte[] encrypted_bytes = new byte[initial_text_bytes.Length];

            int secret_word_index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < initial_text_bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (secret_word_index == secret_word_bytes.Length)
                {
                    secret_word_index = 0;
                }
                encrypted_bytes[i] = (byte)(initial_text_bytes[i] - initial_text_bytes[secret_word_index]);
                secret_word_index++;
            }
           // String s = new String(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(encrypted_bytes));

            initial_text_tb.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);


        }
```

And this is what I get when I encrypt:
[image: After encrypting]
And this is when I decrypt:
[image: After decrypting]
Thanks

Comment: "I'm making a simple custom encrypting " - Don't write your own encryption. It will be flawed...

Comment: You don't seem to be converting back from base64 anywhere...

Comment: Mitch, it's for a lab for uni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see four problems with the code.

#### 1. You are adding bytes from the initial text instead of the secret word.

Here:

```
encrypted_bytes[i] = (byte)(initial_text_bytes[i] + initial_text_bytes[secret_word_index]);
```

Use instead:

```
encrypted_bytes[i] = (byte)(initial_text_bytes[i] + secret_word_bytes[secret_word_index]);
```

#### 2. You are using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` to try to decode the base-64 string.

Here:

```
byte[] initial_text_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text_criptat_tb.Text);
```

Use instead:

```
byte[] initial_text_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text_criptat_tb.Text);
```

#### 3. You are subtracting bytes from the inital text intead of the secret word.

Here:

```
encrypted_bytes[i] = (byte)(initial_text_bytes[i] - initial_text_bytes[secret_word_index]);
```

Use instead:

```
encrypted_bytes[i] = (byte)(initial_text_bytes[i] - secret_word_bytes[secret_word_index]);
```

#### 4. You are using `Convert.ToBase64String` to try to decode the UTF-8 data.

Here:

```
initial_text_tb.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);
```

Use instead:

```
initial_text_tb.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted_bytes);
```